# Versioning for Azure Search index definition schemas

Tags: azure, search, versioning

I'm updating the index/indexer for a search tool, and apart from just making changes to the definition as I tweak it, I'd like to include versioning metadata in the definition, such that it's picked up by my source control solution.

Does anybody have knowledge of where you can include e.g. version numbers in an index definition? The documentation doesn't suggest that you can have custom json fields within the schema without mucking up the validation.

I've got the same question for indexer definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no metadata fields that you could define the version number. I recommend you extract the JSON using the REST APIs and version it on source control by yourself.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index